# Select option value not equal when change value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I try to build a message page for help and support at my web, I use a `<select>` and `<option>`. But when i change a option value from `<select>`, the value return to default value first and then change to next value

This is my select

```
<select
   id="selectMessageSubject"
   defaultValue={this.state.subject}
   onChange={this.handleSubjectChange}
   className="form-control"
>
   <option value="PRAY">{ T.translate('message.pray') }</option>
   <option value="INFO">{ T.translate('message.info') }</option>
   <option value="CARE">{ T.translate('message.treat') }</option>
</select>
```

and this is my function to handle when the value is change

```
handleSubjectChange(evt){
        this.setState({ subject: evt.target.value });
        console.log(this.state.subject);
    }
```

and this is my default value for `<select>`

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state={
       subject: 'PRAY'
   }
this.handleSubjectChange = this.handleSubjectChange.bind(this);
```

Comment: `handleSubjectChange(evt){
        this.setState({ subject: evt.target.value }, () => {
            console.log(this.state.subject);
        });
        
    }` You should check value of state in callback

Comment: Oo, thank you so much @DrewReese that very help me, but i still confuse, why my code not working correctly, any explanation?

Comment: @RyanNghiem, oo ok thank you so much for the help, but still confuse what the difference if i set condole.log outside setState and inside setState? Honestly i new at react so i don't understand react very much

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what "...the value return to default value first and then change to next value" means? Or provide a minimal/complete/reproducible demo in a codesandbox?

Comment: I mean, i have a state name subject and the value is 'PRAY' and at select tag i set subject as default value, i want when i change option my subject value is change, so i use setState to change it, when i run my code, state of subject is change, but for the first time i change option on select tag it not change, but still default value as 'PRAY'

Comment: @MarvinPaulus Does this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wind-mb4o7?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) reproduce the issue you see?

Comment: @DrewReese, yes that the issue i had before

Comment: @MarvinPaulus Check that same sandbox, still repros now?

Comment: @DrewReese my issue not reproduce any more at that sanbox

Comment: @MarvinPaulus Ok, yeah, as expected. You were simply logging the current state value and not the value in the next render cycle after state has been updated.

Comment: @DrewReese Oo, so that is the problem why my state not change when my option value change, because i was logging to current value but not to next value of render cycle. Ok thanks for explanation, you are very helpful

Comment: @MarvinPaulus The state is/was updating, you were just logging it in the wrong way.